# Android MediaCodec for AC-3

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, android-mediacodec

I am trying to decode AC3 audio with the Android MediaCodec API. I can successfully decode AAC provided I set `csd-0` to the [elementary stream descriptor](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=MPEG-4_Audio).

Attempting to decode AC3, I use the following MediaFormat in my configuration:

```
AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_MIME: "audio/ac3"
AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT: 6
AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_SAMPLE_RATE: 48000
AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_IS_ADTS: 0
```

On the call to `AMediaCodec_configure` I get the following error messages:

```
01-22 12:37:58.760: E/ACodec(10548): [OMX.Nvidia.bypass.decoder] configureCodec returning error -2147483648
01-22 12:37:58.760: E/ACodec(10548): signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
01-22 12:37:58.760: E/MediaCodec(10548): Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 3
01-22 12:37:58.760: E/MediaCodec(10548): configure failed with err 0x80001001, resetting...
```

Is there some extra data I need to provide the decoder? I am unfamiliar with the AC3 standard, perhaps there is an equivalent to the elementary stream descriptor that must be provided in `csd-0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official spec on how to handle AC-3 in OpenMAX IL (which is the standard used internally beneath MediaCodec), but despite this, some manufacturers do expose such decoders.

I have earlier tried to do such decoding on a Samsung Galaxy S3, where it did seem to work, and I didn't need to pass any extra data. See https://github.com/mstorsjo/vlc/commit/omxil-ac3 for info about this experiment.

I don't know if this particular Nvidia decoder behaves differently, or if there is something else missing on the ACodec/MediaCodec levels inbetween, that makes it impossible to use. (The example above used internal OMX APIs directly, from before MediaCodec was available.) To complete the answer, I guess I should retest the experiment on the Galaxy S3, both via OMX directly and via MediaCodec, and then on a Nvidia device (is this a Nexus 9 that you're testing on, or something else?).

Comment: Thanks again! Encouraging to hear it worked without any extra data :) I'm using an ADT, but will be getting my hands on some better hardware soon which should hopefully have better support for all the codecs :)

Comment: FWIW, I retested this on a Samsung Galaxy S3 (on an Exynos chipset), and the AC3 decoder seems to work fine via MediaCodec. It's not exposed in MediaCodecList, but if you know the codec name (`OMX.SEC.ac3.dec`) it works. I also checked on Nvidia devices (Nexus 7 2012 and Nexus 9) but neither of them seemed to have any decoders matching `audio/ac3` in the MediaCodecList.

Comment: The name of the decoder in your snippet, `OMX.Nvidia.bypass.decoder`, seems to indicate that the audio wouldn't actually be decoded, but bypassed to some decoder outside of the android device. (IIRC HDMI supports AC3 audio, so it could pass it on along with the screen picture to the TV "hardware".)